# GridView with Caliburn.Micro

Tags: uwp, caliburn.micro

I am working with Caliburn.Micro (UWP). 
and want to run this UWP application on my UWP Caliburn.Micro project.
but Not work.... :(

My Binding Knowledge maybe wrong. Could you help me ?

First [Here is original UWP project from Github](https://github.com/smnbackwards/DragAndDropTest). It is a Drag & Drop enable GridView. Structure is very simple. There is 4 category has books. We can drag and drop a book to change category.

**I want to run it on Caliburn.Micro(UWP).**

[image]

and [I make this code ( I upload it to my GitHub )](https://github.com/bidasknakayama/DragDropUwpCalibrunMicro). In my opinion, It work 50% ..... : )

**Question #1 : How to bind book ? 
There is no display book items... Why ?**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question #1 : How to bind book ? There is no display book items... Why ?

The problem is that you have not initialized your data source in the user control constructor. You could use the following code:

```
public DragDropView()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    categoryCollectionViewSource.Source = new SampleData().GetCategoryDataSource();
    bookCollectionViewSource.Source = new SampleData().GetBookDataSource();
}
```

**DragDropView.xaml**

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource categoryCollectionViewSource}, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

[image]